# how can i access a website that is hosted inside qemu from the host operating system?

Tags: qemu

i have a django application running inside qemu. How can i access that from the host os. I have added "-redir tcp:9000:8000" option at the end but it doesn't seem to work out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. It was not an issue with qemu but with django. insted of using

```
python manage.py runserver
```

i had to use

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```